# Add a Document - SharePoint Online || Deos not display the recently added column to the List

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, column

Looking for a way to add existing newly created column called **Business Area** which is a choice based column to add a document form in SharePoint Online.

This form appear when I try uploading a document in there.

It would be of great help if there is a solution for this at the earliest.

For Example:

I am not able to see a column in the below image which I recently created into one of my list.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you able to see this column in list/library settings? Are there multiple content types or anything added on your list/library??

Comment: Is this SharePoint OOTB form or customized/InfoPath form??

Comment: @GaneshSanap Yes I am able to see the column in the List/ Library - There is a content type. Thank you

Comment: @GaneshSanap not sure if the is created using OOTB

Comment: You need to add this column to the content type (for which you have opened form).

Comment: And if it is a custom form then you need to add newly created column to the custom form.

Comment: @GaneshSanap How to add the column to the content type? Thank you

Comment: Check "Add a column to a list or library content type" section in [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-columns-to-a-content-type-1806e29e-8bcd-4058-b0e7-3aac40a3ae9a) article.

Comment: post a screenshot of your columns in content type

Comment: @harshalgite I have added a screenshot of the columns in there - If you see i would like to add the Business Area Column which is a choice based column

Answer (score 0):

That particular column need to be added in the content type. Go to site setting page - > Site column and content type section > click on content type >find your content type from this page >then click on add column from existing site column, here you can add your column to the content type.

Answer (score 0):

Tejas, I assume you want to add a column to a specific content type. Here is a [tutorial](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-columns-to-a-content-type-1806e29e-8bcd-4058-b0e7-3aac40a3ae9a) about how to do this in classic experience. It is a bit different in UI in modern experience, but the process is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Click on "Document" under Content Types. There will be an option to `Add from existing site or list columns`. Click on it and select "Business Area" and click add.

[image]

Now check if your form has the "Business Area" field on it.

If Content-type is marked read-only, then you can go in "Advanced Settings" of the content type and change it from read-only.

Comment: Tried this i dont see the option to "Add from existing site or List column"

Comment: You need minimum "Design" permissions at site level to modify content types

Comment: I have full control for the Library and i am also a site collections Administrator

Comment: As a work around, you can create the column again (if no data) and then while creating, there is an option to "add to all content types". you can check this and then create the column

Comment: BTW it is weird for you not to see all settings in the content type being a Site Collection Admin.

Comment: is there a way to get this done from the SharePoint Designer? Thank you

Comment: I tried that via SharePoint designer as well but for some reason i am not able to List the column in there when i search for it.

Comment: tried creating New column?

Comment: Just tried creating a new one still the same

Comment: This has been sorted - The issue was with the Content-type marked as read-only

Answer (score 0):

This has been Sorted - The issue was with having the content type set as readonly, Which was changed to be modified which has fixed the issue